# determine the highest real root of f(X)= 2x^3 - 11.7x^2 +17.7x -5 (with python)

Tags: python, numpy

question is about : determine the highest real root of `f(X)= 2x^3 - 11.7x^2 +17.7x -5`

with fixed - point iteration method (three iteration, x0 = 3)

i tried with python code :

```
import numpy as np
x= 1    
for i in range(3):
      x = 2*(x**3)-11.7*(x**2)+17.7*(x)-5
      print(i,x)
```

the answer when i run this code is not right. what is wrong with my code? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the fixed-point iteration method you need to convert your original function `f(x)` into an expression of the form `x = g(x)`. Then iterate using the latter.

This is easy for a polynomial. In your case:

```
x = -(2 * x**3 - 11.7 * x**2 - 5) / 17.7
```

Comment: I use your form but not match what i expect. the root is 3.xxxx , but i run your code (x = -(2 * x**3 - 11.7 * x**2 - 5) / 17.7) and it gives 0.83xxx

Comment: You indicate using `x0 = 3` but you are using 1 as the starting value in your code. Starting from 3, the loop converges to ~3.56 in a few iterations. If you start from 1, it converges to a different root (~0.36).

Comment: oh, you're right!! thank you so much. it helps alot. again, thank you.